# Widgets build() method is called before variables are initialised in flutter State

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently following a Udemy course on Flutter which incorporates some issues one has to solve on their own.
One of these includes building a CYOA app.
Within this app you build a class called `Story` which contains the following story snippet and the 2 possible directions the user can choose to go with afterwards.
All of these `Stories` are held within a List in a class called `StoryBrain`.
One of the tasks at some point asks you to retrieve the first text to start of the story and initialise a `Text` Widget inside of a `_StoryPageState`'s build method.

Like so:

```
Text(
    storyBrain.getStory(),
    style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 25.0,
    ),
),
```

The method `getStory()` just returns the story text from the first `Story` object in the list of stories inside of the `StoryBrain` object.

The issue here is that if I declare and initialise the `StoryBrain` method within the confinements of the `_StoryPageState` class, `getStory()` returns `null`, because it seems that the variable itself or the variables within the object have not yet been initialised.
But if I initialise a `StoryBrain` object on a global level within the same file - outside of any class - , I don't have any issues.

Therefore I have multiple questions:

- When is the *first* build method called? Is it called before variables are initialised? Is it done in a different process/thread?
- How do I encapsulate variables which contain custom datatypes within my StatelessWidget. (Without and/or with using a constructor)
- Is it good practice to initialise variables within the build method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) The first build method is called as soon as the page is loaded.

2.) You need to define them after defining your class, and initialize them in the same line, or in your class constructor.

3.) Absolutely not. Initialization of variables should be done at the initialization of a class, or in the object's initState method (which is only done in a StatefulWidget, and only runs once).

In regards to your original question, you need to either initialize your variables when you make the class, or pass in your variables from the previous screen through the constructor, and instantiate them there.